# How to get the point of reflection given two points and a plane?

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry, reflection

I'm working on a 3D simulation, and I need to find two vectors: 1. from the viewer to a point on a water plane, and 2. from the point on the water plane to the sun. 
 What I know is that I can use reflection math to reflect a given vector, but I do not have a vector to reflect, which is my problem.

1. I have the X,Y,Z viewer point (lets say on a hill, Y = 40), and the X,Y,Z sun point.
2. I have the water line (at a given height [like Y=20]). Up (plane normal) is 0,1,0.

Given two points and a plane how do I find the point on the plane where the reflection occurs?  Once I find that point I can get the other vectors (that's the easy part). I imagine that if I can deduce the angle on one side I can easily use geometry to reflect it, but I'm struggling with finding that angle, or even if that is the right approach to getting a point on the plane, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange! I'm confused by one part of your question- which point are you trying to reflect, and with respect to what?

Comment: Picture a guy on a small hill overlooking the water and the sun in the distance.  The sun is reflecting off the water.   I only have the 3D point of the viewer, and the 3D point of the sun.  What I need, assuming a perfect mirror (water plane), is a point on that water plane where the reflection occurs.

Comment: Reflect the sun in the lake $ y \rightarrow -y $ to a point $ S^{'}$ See where $ES^{'}$ cuts the lake surface,(Eye position is $E$).

Comment: There's more to it that a sun.  I need a point on the plane based on the viewer's location. The sun can reflect off a mirror from any angle, but only one point on a plane given a single observable point.

Comment: Narasimham’s suggestions takes both into account.

Comment: I just saw him update and add "Eye position is E" (after I made the comment). ;)  Ok, thanks. I have no idea what any of that means, but I guess I have a bit more to learn. ;)

Comment: Ah ok, I wrote it down, now it makes sense! lol.  You meant that negating the sun's Y position to -Y is the start of the line to the player's eye, then I just need to find a point intersection between a line and a plane! Got it. ;) I didn't occur to me that negating the Y would give me the start of the line, but now it makes sense (given you are looking directly at the object, but inverted). Thanks everyone. Someone should make that an answer, so I can give you the points.